# Where to find and how to get Kovan USDC testnet tokens

Tags: tokens, testnets, testing, kovan, usdc

I need USDC Kovan testnet tokens transffered to this address `0x2E9b971e336C825BC41b9FE87376E74f0B3345FE` for testing purposes.
Token contract for this token is https://kovan.etherscan.io/token/0xe22da380ee6b445bb8273c81944adeb6e8450422

How can I get these tokens? I see there are a lot of people (more than 83,400 holders as of date) who have them. How did they acquire this token? :)

Is there a faucet for this? Or I could get them perhaps by using Kovan ETH? Can I buy them?

Is it easier to get tokens on some other ETH testnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://staging.aave.com/#/faucet. You just connect with your Metamask wallet on Kovan testnet and select USD Coin. You will be prompted to accept the metamask transaction and after you will receive 10000 USDC tokens. You just add the address you provided here to Metamask to see your tokens and you're all set.

Comment: Careful now! I specificly asked for the USDC token for 0xe22da380ee6b445bb8273c81944adeb6e8450422 contract. You supplied the link for the 0xc2569dd7d0fd715b054fbf16e75b001e5c0c1115 contract. If you edit that I will accept your answer. :) Thanks :)

Comment: Edited the answer. Now it should work with the address you provided.

Comment: That link is the one where you get your USDC token with that specific contract address for Kovan network. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it is, however you significantly changed your answer. I believe the best practice is to create another answer if you want to change everything in your answer.
You only needed to change the contract address in your original answer to this: https://kovan.balancer.fi/#/trade/0xdfcea9088c8a88a76ff74892c1457c17dfeef9c1/0xe22da380ee6b445bb8273c81944adeb6e8450422

Comment: I also needed more time to check whether your new answer is suitable for my needs. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Kovan is deprecated along with Rinkeby and Ropsten. Therefore, make sure to get Goerli testETH from a reliable faucet (like https://goerlifaucet.com) b/c there's lots of scam out there. Uniswap is a good option to switch between tokens.